# Frameworks to generate UUID key for Hibernate Persistence?

Tags: java, guid, uuid

what are the Open source Frameworks to generate globally identifiable id for Table primary key before persist?

For example Google Appengine's KeyFactory to generate Key

Comment: Could you please give more information on your use case? Considerations include: sharded databases and requirements for sequential UUIDs.

Comment: actually I am looking for pre-persist key generating technique.

Comment: Hibernate provides such a UUID ID generator. You don't need anything more. Read the documentation. Also, note that even if Hibernate didn't, the JDK comes with a UUID class.

Comment: How about token number generation?